# how to replace some character b/w strings in c#?

Tags: c#, string

how to replace some character b/w strings in c#?

suppose

string is :   `1-2-5-7-8-9-10-15`

i use replace function

when i replace `5` with `2`

it also replace the last `15` to `12` because of `5` there.

so how can i get the right output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
yourString.Split("-").Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, "^5$", "2")).Aggregate((a,b) => a + "-" + b);
```

In contrast to most of the other answers here, this also handles the case, when the string to be replaced is at the beginning or the end of the input string.

Comment: I like this because it will work for any set, where as my solution only works for the example set.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Regex(@"\b5\b").Replace("1-2-5-7-8-9-10-15", "2");
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary. This means that '-5-' will be matched but '-15-' won't.

It will will also handle the case where the match is at the edge of the string and does not have a hyphen on both sides, e.g. '5-' and '-5'.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to replace -5- with -2-

Comment: +1 Though your approach only works for the example set and not for a set with different delimiters, I prefer your solution over the regex ones because yours is way easier to read, and less heavy. I think with some minor tweaking your approach will suit the OP's need and doesn't require expensive regex.

Comment: @Bazzz: I don't think this can be tweaked in a way that matches all requirements. And a simple solution that doesn't work correctly isn't a solution in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
yourString = yourString.Replace("-5-","-2-");
```

Comment: @Pawel there is no 5 in that set, so there is nothing to replace.  If you were trying to have a set with a leading 5, then neither @Stecya nor my solution will work.  For that, use the solution from @Daniel.

Comment: @SAHIL SINGLA - You should consider to use Daniel Hilgarth solution, because it handles all situations

Answer (score 2):

you could use a regex replace and replace with a regex something like

`[^\d]*5[^\d]*` to match a 5 without any numbers next to it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separator?

E.g. If you really have the string link 1-2-5... you can replace '-5' with -2.

Comment: if there is `-52-` you will end with `-22-`